# How to create File from bytes in S3 Bucket if it does not exist yet using AWS Java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am writing a code that creates a file on S3 Bucket. This file contains the bytes which are the parameter of the method. I am using this code but it returns a

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException

```
S3Client client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).build();

public void writeBytesToS3(byte[] data) {
    PutObjectRequest request = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket("mybucket").key("java-aws-s3/file.tmp").build();
    client.putObject(request, RequestBody.fromBytes(data));
}
```

I know that it means that the "java-aws-s3/file.tmp" does not exist on the S3. But shouldn't the putObject automatically create that file as a container for my bytes? Or I am doing this the wrong way.

Comment: your code works fine with software.amazon.awssdk version  2.0.0-preview-10

Comment: Your code should work perfectly fine provided you have S3 bucket with name "mybucket" and IAM role has permission to putObject to "mybucket" s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

First I don't know which version for amazon library you are using..

To put any object in s3 aws s3 client provides variety of ways.
in your case by seeing you method signature my below code will help i think
Wrap your Request into PutObjectRequest class

Example:-
void putObjectInS3(byte []data){
PutObjectRequest por=new PutObjectRequest("buck_name","java-aws-s3/file.tmp",(String)null);
s3Client.putObject(por);
}

PutObjectRequest has constructor overloading with have various constructors 
In 1st parameter specify bucket_name,
In 2nd parameter specify file_name,
In 3rd parameter use specify redirection link(used when if get request is comming for Object A in s3 you and redirec to some other file in same bucket or in other buckets in your case i passed as null